# For loop keeps crashing Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code and there is a For loop in it that keeps crashing excel. I've used a for loop this way before to find duplicates and it's worked fine, but this one keeps causing problems.

The code is

```
`Dim i As Long, j As Long
Sheets("Yesterday_Kickbacks").Rows(1).Copy Sheets("WO_MULTIPLE_KB").Range("A1")
Sheets("Yesterday_Kickbacks").Sort.SortFields.Clear
Range("B:B").Sort key1:=Range("B1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Dim doubles As Long
doubles = Sheets("Yesterday_Kickbacks").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlDown).Row
j = 2
For i = 2 To doubles
If Sheets("Yesterday_Kickbacks").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Yesterday_Kickbacks").Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
Sheets("Yesterday_Kickbacks").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("WO_MULTIPLE_KB").Range("A" & j)
    j = j + 1
End If
Next`
```

Basically, in a list of work orders that had problems, I'm trying to find if any work orders had more than one issue. So going down field 2, if the entry in the cell is the same as above, copy and paste the row into another sheet that will be added to a new workbook that gets created later.

Comment: "Crashing" with what particular error message?  The error details would be helpful

Comment: Also, have you stepped through, line-by-line, in debug, to determine exactly which line is causing the exception?

Comment: I'll also clarify, I get no error message-compile shows syntax is good. It runs for a minute then sends excel into (Not Responding).
Also, I have stepped through and had no issues. It's when I run even just this block (the loop specifically) that it crashes. 
Lastly, there is 30 rows it is looping through.

Comment: `Not Responding` is not a crash.  For long running code, after a while Excel stops updating the UI, and displays that message.   The is still running.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Duplicates

- Your code is not crashing Excel. It is just taking forever since you have incorrectly calculated the last row (`doubles`). You just need to replace `xlDown` with `xlUp` and you're good to go.

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyDupes()
    
    ' Constants
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy Duplicates"

    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Yesterday_Kickbacks"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "WO_MULTIPLE_KB"
    Const CRIT_COLUMN As Long = 2
    
    ' Workbook
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, surg As Range
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set surg = .Rows(1) ' reference headers
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(CRIT_COLUMN)
    
    ' Sort by the criteria column.
    sws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    srg.Sort scrg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    
    Dim sCell As Range, sr As Long, drCount As Long, IsNotFirst As Boolean
    
    ' Combine the matching source rows into the range with the headers ('surg').
    For Each sCell In scrg.Cells
        sr = sr + 1
        If IsNotFirst Then
            If CStr(sCell.Value) = CStr(sCell.Offset(-1).Value) Then
                Set surg = Union(surg, srg.Rows(sr)) ' combine
                drCount = drCount + 1 ' count
            End If
        Else
            IsNotFirst = True
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    ' If not found, inform and exit.
    If drCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Copy
    
    surg.Copy dfCell
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox drCount & "duplicate row" & IIf(drCount = 1, "", "s") & " copied.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: That did it. I swear i had tried that with no change, but i changed it and it's working now. Thank you!